# Medieval fantasy book where an evil sorcerer tried to use magic to make the new weapon, a cannon, explode

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I've been trying to remember a book, but for the life of me I can't.  I read this in middle school, about 10 or 12 years ago, but the book looked older then.  It was set in a medieval time period, but one of the plot points was the villain was going to use magic to make a cannon explode and kill the king (brand new invention I think, and to make it explode so people would not want to use them because they would be "dangerous").  The main character was a female warrior, she may have been a priestess.  I think the main villain was a demon or sorcerer, but I'm not for sure.  I can remember on the cover there was a dragon, and 2 character wearing blue and yellow I'm pretty certain.

After the cannon incident (didn't explode, heroine stopped the magic), I think an invisible army was revealed and the castle where this was taking place was then under siege.

Our library shelves were sorted by author, and I am pretty sure that Paul Stewart, author of the *Edge Chronicles*, was either on the shelf above or below this book. So the author's last name could have started with an S, but to be safe, maybe R or T as well.

Comment: There are elements of this that strongly suggest Stackpole's Dragoncrown trilogy.

Comment: @JohnPno as far as I know it was a single book. It was wrapped up at the end, no cliff hanger or sign of a continuing story.

Comment: Although it's not a perfect match, this reminds me a lot of Terry Pratchett's "Interesting Times"

Answer (score 3):

This is an extreme long shot but I am going to suggest *The Last Days of the Edge of the World* by Brian Stableford. The setting is medieval or fantasy based as you describe and the main character is a resourceful female sorcerer. The cover features a dragon like creature and two characters dressed in blue and yellow. Here is a link to an image of the cover which may jog your memory.

[image: The Last Days of the Edge of the World front cover]

The author's name falls in the correct area of the alphabet as you suggest. It also features a defined ending with no cliffhanger and is not part of a series. It is more than twenty five years since I read this so can't be certain about the other plat elements you describe. I do recall a scene in a castle but am unable to recall the scene you mention with a cannon.

Comment: I looked up a summary of the book and I don't think it was this one.  The art work seemed a bit similar in style, not in content, so I looked up the author and went through a list of books.  No luck there unless it was one of the ones listed without a cover.

Comment: @bubbajake00 sorry it turned out to be a wild goose chase. I did think it was a long shot seeing as it was based primarily on where the authors name might lie in the alphabet. Well... let's keep looking. You never know you might find it yet.